# SQL Server "Shared Memory provider" Error

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I am running the following command in a batch file:

```
osql -S dbname -U username -P password -i C:\inputSQL.sql -o C:\postMigration.log -n
```

The dbname, username, and password have all been set correctly.

However , when I run the batch file I get this output to the "C:\postMigration.log" log

```
 [SQL Native Client]Shared Memory Provider: No process is on the other
end of the pipe.
[SQL Native Client]Communication link failure
```

My question is: what can cause SQL Server 2005 to throw this error? Is it a login issue?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you miss -H (host) param. Also note -o would work relative server's disk C: